# amp-layout using layout attribute with forms

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I'm trying to build an amp page for my site.

I am trying to achieve a responsive form with a number of range inputs.

[image: mockup of form field]

So that when the screen size changes they stack nicely, much as I would when using bootstrap.

The code I have is (as a single example);

```
    <div class="form-field" layout="container">
        <div class="form-title" layout="responsive">
            <span>How much do you need?</span>
            <span [text]="[amount]">
                £1500000
            </span>
        </div>
        <div layout="responsive" width="auto" height=100>
            <input type="range"
                   name="amountSlider"
                   min="10000"
                   step="10000"
                   value="1500000"
                   max="3000000"
                   on="change:AMP.setState({amount: '£' + event.value})">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now when I add the `layout` attribute to the div. All elements inside disappear. When I inspect the html it seems to be applying the css;

```
.i-amphtml-notbuilt, [layout]:not(.i-amphtml-element) {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    color: transparent!important;
}
```

Now as far as I can see from reading the docs I am compliant with the amp specification, however I must be doing something wrong here?

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong an dhow I Can achieve the layout above?

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew-Flynn

The text was disappearing because of `color: transparent!important;`. I removed that in the code snippet below. But I'm not sure that answers your positioning question: could you build out this snippet a little more and I'll take a look?

```css
.i-amphtml-notbuilt, [layout]:not(.i-amphtml-element) {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field" layout="container">
        <div class="form-title" layout="responsive">
            <span>How much do you need?</span>
            <span [text]="[amount]">
                £1500000
            </span>
        </div>
        <div layout="responsive" width="auto" height=100>
            <input type="range"
                   name="amountSlider"
                   min="10000"
                   step="10000"
                   value="1500000"
                   max="3000000"
                   on="change:AMP.setState({amount: '£' + event.value})">
        </div>
    </div>
```